# How do I create a promise in Ember.js for an Ember-data model

Tags: ember.js, promise

I have an Ember-Data model. I would like to do some processing in the .then promise once it has loaded and then return the same model as a promise. This is what I have right now. How do I wrap up the return object as a promise so that other promises can be chained?

```
App.Member.find(1).then(function(member){

  //do some processing here
  return member; // Does this need to be wrapped as a promise?

}
```

Comment: Once you return a result that is not another `promise` from any `thenable` it is considered to be resolved. So just returning `member` is equivalent to wrapping it inside another `promise` and manually calling `resolve`. You only need a wrapper `promise` if the `member` was going to be obtained by another async operation.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Basically you can create a promise like this:

```
var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
  // succeed
  resolve(value);
  // or reject
  reject(error);
});
```

and then you can use the `then` property to chain it further:

```
promise.then(function(value) {
  // success
}, function(value) {
  // failure
});
```

You can aslo have a look at this [jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ipehoj/1/edit) which shows how they could be implemented. And [this](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js) is also very helpful.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey shouldn resolve, reject be part of then?? or have i got it wrong.
I mean what is the difference between resolve, reject and success, failure in promise(function(resolve,reject){}).then(success,failue);
I assume once promise returns true then success gets called in "then", if it returns false then failure gets called?