# Problems with handling arrays gotten from php by using jquery ajax

Tags: arrays, json, function, jquery

Goog Morning, everyone.

I still have some problems trying to use arrays which were gotten from php. The problem is that when I got an array , I can not use it out of the "success function". So this is what is happening.

I create a var called "langs" to save array's information:

```
var langs=[];
```

Then, when I use console.log for print array's information INSIDE function success, my code seems like this:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ws/languagesForJs',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
            langs=result;
            console.log(result)         
      },
  });
```

It works Great!! I can see the array's information. It looks like this:

```
Object {es: Object, en: Object}
 en: Object
       lang_ext_name: "en_US"
       lang_id: 2
       lang_iso: "en"
       lang_name: "Inglés"
       lang_url: "en"
      __proto__: Object
 es: Object
       lang_ext_name: "es_PE"
       lang_id: 1
       lang_iso: "es"
       lang_name: "Español"
       lang_url: "es"
 __proto__: Object
 __proto__: Object
```

HOWEVER,When I use console.log for print array's information OUTSIDE function success:

```
$.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: '/ws/languagesForJs',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(result) {
            langs=result;

      },
  });
            console.log(result)
```

It returns just;

```
[]
```

Sincerely, I do not know why is it happens. Maybe I'm missing some function's theory or something. I've looked for info on the web;however, it seems that no one needs an array outside success functions. I haven't found any information about it.

I hope someone can help me. Thanks

Btw: Sorry for my bad english. It is not my mother language.

Comment: `result` is a local variable to the success function, it cannot be referenced outside of that function. Are you declaring result above the AJAX call as well?

Comment: No,my friend. I just declaring langs for saving the return data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 issues here.

1. result is local to the success callback. You have access to langs outside of the callback since it doesn't appears to be globally scoped.
2. The callback happens asynchronously. This will likely cause the console.log call to happen before the success callback. It might be worthwile to look into the jQuery ajax promise objects, http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/.

Comment: Asynchronous; can't stress that enough!

Comment: Seriously, I need to read more. It was true that the "console.log" ran before receiving the data. I have added the option "async: false" and I can see the information again, even if I use the array from outside the function. The issue of asynchrony on calls with "ajax" is extensive. Thanks for all your responses and you pacience.

Comment: async:false is deprecated as of jQuery 1.8. It also causes the browser to lock until after the ajax call. I highly recommend using the promise callbacks. Here's a good blog post about different ways of using the deferred promises. http://www.erichynds.com/blog/using-deferreds-in-jquery

Answer (score 1):

The `result` is a local variable, you need to create a reference outside your ajax call, this way you can reference it without problems.

Try this:

```
var myResult;
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/ws/languagesForJs',
  dataType: 'json'})
  .done(function(result) {
     myResult = result; // save a reference
     langs = result;
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log(myResult);
  });
```

I should also mention that `success` is deprecated and you should go for `done` instead. The `always` callback is called as the names say's *always* so you can put there code that needs to be executed when the async call is done.

Hope it helps.

Comment: You get a big hairy downvote because this does pretty much the same thing as the original code, and _doesn't fix the problem_

Comment: I've removed the downvote because it technically works, but if you think about it you could just put the `console.log()` in the `.done()` call

Comment: @Bojangles, thanks and yes, you are right one more time :) just wanted to show a different ajax callback where things can also be safely put

Comment: That's fair enough then `:)`. I quite like how the jQuery deferred stuff works

Comment: @Bojangles I like it to, it's just that I'm more used to `ember.js` implementation of it - RVSP.js see here for an answer of mine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475657/how-do-i-create-a-promise-in-ember-js-for-an-ember-data-model/17476002#17476002