# Why does not LSAdapter trigger the loading event in Ember.js?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, local-storage, loading

I am working with the LSAdapter , and trying to get the loading event work .
I found this strange problem ,that loading event seems not working properly.

Here is a simple page .

--When we work with DS.FixtureAdapter . The loading event works fine 
--When we work with  DS.LSAdapter .the loading event does not work ?

Am I making any mistakes?

```
  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="application">
    <h1>ember-latest jsbin</h1>
    {{outlet}}
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
    {{input value = newBookTitle action= 'newBook'}}
    <ul>
      {{#each}}
        <li>{{title}} </li>
      {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </script>

  <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="loading">
    <div id = 'global-loading'>
      <h2>GLOBAL LOADING</h2>
     </div> 
  </script>

  <script>
    App = Ember.Application.create({
      LOG_TRANSITIONS: true,
      LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true
    });

    //Why does LSAdapter doesnot trigger the loading event?
    // App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.LSAdapter.extend({namespace: 'App-test-loading'});

    // FixtureAdapter works fine with loading event
    App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.FixtureAdapter.extend();

    App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
      title: DS.attr('string'),
    });

    App.Book.FIXTURES = [
        {
        id: 1,
        title: 'Learn Ember.js',
        },
        {
        id: 2,
        title: 'Nothing more'
        }
    ];

    App.ApplicationRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      actions: {
        loading: function() {
          alert('laoding');
        }
      }
    });

    App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
      model: function() {
          return this.store.find('book');
      }
    });

    App.IndexController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
      newBookTitle:'',
      actions:{
        newBook:function(){
          var _nb = this.get('newBookTitle');
          if(!_nb) return ;

          var _book = this.store.createRecord('book',{
            id: Math.random().toString(32).slice(2).substr(0, 5),
            title: _nb
          });
          _book.save();

          this.set('newBookTitle', '');
        }
      }
    });

  </script>
```

_______UPDATE_________

With the kind help from @GJK

I solve it in this way :

```
   /*IndexRoute   model hook*/
  var books = this.store.find('book');
  return new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve) {
    Ember.run.later(function() {
      resolve(books);
    }, 10);
   });
```

also get help from

1 [How do I create a promise in Ember.js for an Ember-data model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475657/how-do-i-create-a-promise-in-ember-js-for-an-ember-data-model)

2 http://jsbin.com/ipehoj/1/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the FixtureAdapter tries to simulate a remote server while the LSAdapter doesn't. [From the FixtureAdapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/39483b7b3487fc4a6ebb596ca7c9fcfea5abcc7f/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/fixture_adapter.js#L149):

```
return this.simulateRemoteCall(function() {
```

The Fixture adapter actually waits a set amount of time to more closely resemble an actual server call (which is the whole purpose of the FixtureAdapter). But [look at the LSAdapter](https://github.com/kurko/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/cdedb282b454da73c50eecef94154c45ed9791a5/localstorage_adapter.js#L130):

```
return Ember.RSVP.resolve(record);
```

It returns a promise that resolves almost immediately, leaving no time for your loading event to get called.

The LSAdapter is supposed to be a production-ready adapter that stores your data in the browser. Because it's stored in the browser, *there are (almost) no loading times.* The FixtureAdapter on the other hand, is supposed to simulate a production-ready adapter *that will having loading times.* Their purposes are different, you shouldn't use them interchangeably.