# Sequencing a series of functions with promises in Ember js

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I wasn't sure how to title this question.

What I am looking to do is grab a large array of movies, filter out only those that have reviews, then sort the reviews by date desc, then trim the list to grab only the latest 11 before setting the first entry to be featured and returning to the model then. With these numerous calls though, I notice some data being jumbled out of order and I believe it's due to all the calls running simultaneously. How can I use promises to structure this to wait for the previous step to complete before proceeding?

```
getLatestReviews(num) {
    const movieList = this.getMovies();
    const reviewList = movieList.filterBy('review');
    const indexList = this.sortReviewsByDate(reviewList);
    const latestList = this.getSetAmountOfMovies(num, reviewList);
    return this.setFirstReviewToFeatured(latestList);
},


sortReviewsByDate(arr, dir) {
    dir = dir || 'desc';

    return arr.sort(function(a,b) {
        if (dir === 'desc') { 
            return a.review.date < b.review.date;
        } else {
            return a.review.date > b.review.date;
        }
    });
},
getSetAmountOfMovies(num, arr) {
    const movieList = arr ? null : this.getMovies();
    const trimmedList = arr ? arr.slice(0, num) : movieList.slice(0, num);        
    return trimmedList;
},
setFirstReviewToFeatured(arr) {
    arr[0].isFeatured = true;
    return arr;
},
```

What I'm experience is once I exceed 10 reviews the ordering starts getting out of whack and I believe it's due to the functions not running in a sequence. But I'm not sure how to use promises to ensure one step is complete before running the next.

Comment: Do these functions actually return promises? If no, then start with fixing that.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: Not without you showing us what these methods are that you're calling. Or are they standard Ember functions that have documentation somewhere (I don't know Ember)? The question of interest is which of these parts are actually asynchronous - none of those you have shown seem to be (`sort` and `slice` in particular are not for sure)

Comment: I believe the actual problem you are experiencing ("*the ordering starts getting out of whack*") is caused by [the broken comparison function for `sort`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/24080785/1048572) and that there is nothing asynchronous at all.

Comment: Thanks, @Bergi that got me on the right track to solving this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use promise chain to avoid asynchronous problems :

```
getLatestReviews(num) {
    return this.getMovies().then(function(movieList) {
       return movieList.filterBy('review');
    }).then(function(reviewList) {
       return //...
    });
},
```

Comment: You should [chain instead of nest](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22000931/1048572) though

Comment: I'm not sure I follow how to implement this. There closing parenthesis on line 3; what is that closing?

Comment: This now creates the following error: TypeError: this.getMovies(...).then is not a function

Comment: Does `this.getMovies(...)` return a promise ? I don't think so, and that's why you get this error.

Comment: However, I'm not sure how to return a promise that contains the array. Do I need to import anything from Ember to call new Promise?

Comment: Please see [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475657](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17475657/)